# AdMob not displaying on copied Swift project

Tags: swift, admob

I have created an app in swift and it’s in the app store, displaying Google AdMobs interstitial.
Let’s call the app ‘MyApp’, and bundle identifier is ‘com.mrx.-MyApp’.

Now, I’ve made a copy of this app, it has the same name, and some minor modifications, and just changed the bundle identifier to ‘com.mrx.-MyAppTwo’. That’s it. The display name is still ‘MyApp’ (not ‘MyApp Two’) and the ‘Name’ (under ‘Identity and type’) is also still just ‘MyApp’.

No other changes in the projects settings (no renaming or anything, since the app’s name is the same).

I’ve create a new AdMobs using the app name ‘MyApp Two’ and the bundle identifier ‘com.mrx.-MyAppTwo’.

However, it will simply not display adds (it works fine with AdMob’s sample ads).

My guess is that it has something to do with the naming, but I can simply not figure it out.

Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In simulator or in device , the ad shows just one time. You can use test ad for this.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like just renaming it under 'Identity and Type' did the trick.